# Modbus TCPIP flutter/dart exception error

Tags: flutter, dart, modbus-tcp

I want to develop an app for requesting some datas from a device with modbus TCP /IP. I used flutter in order to create it but I have an error:

E/flutter ( 7330): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null

In attachment there are the flie...would you like to help me,please?
Any help will be very useful....

Thank you!!!!

```
main.dart
import 'package:primo_schermo/Schermi.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initScreen();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    releaseResource();
  }

  build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: new Text(' XT MONITOR'),
      ),
      body: OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
        if (orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
          return potraitFirstScreen(context);
        } else {
          return landscapeFirstScreen(context);
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}

  
Schermi.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:modbus/modbus.dart' as modbus;

String address = '127.0.1.1';
int port = 400;

bool verifylenghtport = false;
bool verifylenghtaddr = false;

//UserModbus userModbus;
TextEditingController usraddress = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController usrport = TextEditingController();

Widget landscapeFirstScreen(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        // Logo DKC

        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('images/Dkc.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        // Textfield insert  ip

        Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            child: TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                hintText: "Insert IP UPS Address...",
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9.]')),
              ],
              controller: usraddress,
              onChanged: (text) {
                if (usraddress.text.length > 4) {
                  verifylenghtaddr = true;
                } else {
                  verifylenghtaddr = false;
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.02,
        ),

        // Textfield insert  port
        Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            child: TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                hintText: "Insert Port...",
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9.]')),
              ],
              controller: usrport,
              onChanged: (text) {
                if (usrport.text.length == 3) {
                  verifylenghtport = true;
                } else {
                  verifylenghtport = false;
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.02,
        ),
        Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[
          ButtonTheme(
            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.98,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.13,
            child: FlatButton(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
              color: Colors.black,
              textColor: Colors.red,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              onPressed: enableconnectionbutton() ? connectUPS : null,
              child: Text(
                "Connect".toUpperCase(),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

/*
 *  Widget portratit 
 *  
 */

Widget potraitFirstScreen(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('images/Dkc.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                hintText: "Insert IP UPS Address...",
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9.]')),
              ],
              controller: usraddress,
              onChanged: (text) {
                if (usraddress.text.length > 4) {
                  verifylenghtaddr = true;
                } else {
                  verifylenghtaddr = false;
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
        ),
        Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                hintText: "Insert Port...",
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9.]')),
              ],
              controller: usrport,
              onChanged: (text) {
                if (usrport.text.length == 3) {
                  verifylenghtport = true;
                } else {
                  verifylenghtport = false;
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04,
        ),
        Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[
          ButtonTheme(
            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.89,
            height: 20,
            child: FlatButton(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
              color: Colors.black,
              textColor: Colors.red,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              onPressed: enableconnectionbutton() ? connectUPS : null,
              child: Text(
                "Connect".toUpperCase(),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

void initScreen() {
  
 
  usraddress.addListener(remCharAddr);
  usrport.addListener(remCharPort);
}

void remCharPort() {
  String cr = "\r";
  final text =
      usrport.text.replaceAll("-", "").replaceAll(",", "").replaceAll(cr, "");

  usrport.value = usrport.value.copyWith(
      text: text,
      selection:
          TextSelection(baseOffset: text.length, extentOffset: text.length),
      composing: TextRange.empty);
}

void remCharAddr() {
  String cr = "\r";
  final text = usraddress.text
      .replaceAll("-", "")
      .replaceAll(",", "")
      .replaceAll(cr, "");

  usraddress.value = usraddress.value.copyWith(
      text: text,
      selection:
          TextSelection(baseOffset: text.length, extentOffset: text.length),
      composing: TextRange.empty);
}

void releaseResource() {
  usraddress.dispose();
  usrport.dispose();
}

void connectUPS() {
  //userModbus.address = usraddress.text;
  address = usraddress.text;
  port = int.parse(usrport.text);

  //print("Address:" + userModbus.address);
  //print("Port:" + userModbus.port.toString());

  //connect(userModbus.address, userModbus.port);
  connecttoUPS(address, port);
}

bool enableconnectionbutton() {
  if (verifylenghtaddr && verifylenghtport) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

void connecttoUPS(String address, int porta) async {
  //int error = 0;

  //String ip = '127.0.0.1';
  //int p = 502;

  var client =
      modbus.createTcpClient(address, port: porta, mode: modbus.ModbusMode.rtu);
  try {
    await client.connect();
  } finally {
    var registers = await client.readInputRegisters(0x0006, 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < registers.length; i++) {
      print("REG_I:" + registers.elementAt(i).toString());
    }
  }
  client.close();
}
```